# jQuery Validation plugin: how to check if an element is valid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

A little bit of context:

I'm using the *jQuery Validation plugin* to validate a sign-up form. I now want to implement an **ajax call to check whether the user name is available** in the system, and I want to make this ajax call only if the userName value is a valid one as per the rules set in `$(form).validate();`

I want something like:

```
$("#userName").keyup(function () {
    if ($("#userName").isValid()) {
        //make ajax called
    }
});
```

I searched the documentation but i couldn't identify the solution to my problem.

Comment: The plugin contains the `remote` method specifically for this task.

Answer (score 46):

```
$("#userName").keyup(function () {
    if ($("#userName").valid() == true ) {
        //make ajax called
    }
});
```

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/valid

*Note:* To those who do not click the link. You have to call `$("#myform").validate();` first.

Comment: A quick note to those who do not click the link. You have to call `$("#myform").validate();` first.

Comment: Note that this code doesn't run at all if the user inputs the name via, say, right click, Paste. Use remote.

Comment: Use focusout instead of keyup. And $("#myform").validate() is not required for manual validation.

Comment: I think that's wrong. the valid() delegates the check to the form of the element, so if another element of the form is invalid but the one you check is valid, the answer will still be 'true'

Answer (score 8):

Validator.element()

> Description: Validates a single element, returns true if it is valid,
>   false otherwise.

http://jqueryvalidation.org/Validator.element

Comment: That is to trigger validation. The OP asked how to check if it is valid

Comment: @user2903379 read the docs: Validates a single element, returns true if it is valid, false otherwise. You see what I did there? RETURNS TRUE IF VALID

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me on JQuery 1.11

```
$("#userName").keyup(function () {
    if ($(this)[0].validity.valid) {
        // AJAX here
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello i find exclusive solution, i have the same problem as 47k others & i discover the solution without other jquery plugins or libraries:
-first of all we need to register our input in a variable, 
-then on change checkValidity() if true:mean if valid we assign the registered var to our input to rest it for next change.

```
        ivar=$('input[name="y-i-name"]')[0];
        $('input[name="y-i-name"]').on('change',function(){
             if($('input[name="y-i-name"]')[0].checkValidity()){


                     // your custom code here!



                     $('input[name="y-i-name"]')[0]=ivar; // & now we rest the input for next change validation
             }
        });
```